# How can I add a CASE expression in mikro-orm querybuilder?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, case, mikro-orm

I need to translate this sentence

```
SELECT "si".*, 
       (CASE 
          WHEN sip_mapping.sip_identity_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' 
        END) AS available
```

to mikro-orm querybuilder but I can't find the way to do it.
Is there a way to add a new field to the records using querybuilder?

Answer (score -1):

use the `expr()` method in Mikro-ORM QueryBuilder to add a new field to the records using a `CASE` expression

```js
const siRepository = orm.em.getRepository(Si);
const qb = siRepository.createQueryBuilder('si')
  .leftJoin('si.sipMapping', 'sip_mapping')
  .addSelect(qb.expr().selectCase()
    .when('sip_mapping.sipIdentityId IS NOT NULL', 'false')
    .else('true')
    .end()
    .as('available')
  );
const results = await qb.getMany();
```

Comment: MikroORM query builder doesn't have `expr()` method